# No me imprime nada después de aplicar una función en java

Tags: java, poo

Tengo que hacer un programa que consiste en **un mago que tiene que pelear con N dragones y devolver cuanto daño le hicieron al mago**.
El programa **debe leer el daño por turno de cada dragón y sus respectivos puntos de salud.**
El mago tiene restricciones para atacar:
**Le pega a un dragón a la vez.
Debe derrotar a los dragones en orden en base a sus puntos de salud.
Los dragones vivos atacan simultáneamente al mago.**

Se debe implementar una clase Dragon con los metodos get y set, esto lo hice

```
public class Dragon {
//Atributos
private int dps;
private int ps;

//metodos
public Dragon(int dps, int ps){
    this.dps = dps;
    this.ps = ps;
}

public int getDPS(){
    return dps;
}
public int getPS(){
    return ps;
}

public void setDPS(int dps){
    this.dps = dps;
}
public void setPS(int ps){
    this.ps = ps;
}}
```

Se debe implementar 1 función que ordene el arreglo de los dragones en orden ascendente en base a los Puntos de salud(ps).
Y otra que devuelva el daño recibido del mago.

Esto lo hice en el main class

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int dps = 0;
    int ps = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese un entero de dragones");

    int n = reader.nextInt();

    Dragon arrayDragon[] = new Dragon[n];//declara el arreglo tipo dragon

    for(int i=0 ; i<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
        arrayDragon[i] = new Dragon(dps, ps); //instansiamos(crear) el objeto

        System.out.println("Ingrese el dps del dragon"+ i+1);
        dps = reader.nextInt();

        arrayDragon[i].setDPS(dps);

        System.out.println("Ingrese los ps del dragon"+ i+1);
        ps = reader.nextInt();

        arrayDragon[i].setPS(ps);
    }

    ordenaDragones(arrayDragon);

    for(int i=0 ; i<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("El dragon "+ i+1 +" tiene un dps de");
        System.out.println(arrayDragon[i].getDPS() +" dps");
        System.out.println("El dragon "+ i+1 +" tiene ");
        System.out.println(arrayDragon[i].getPS() +" ps");

    }

    System.out.println("El daño recibido del mago es");
    System.out.println(danoRecibido(arrayDragon));

}

public static void ordenaDragones(Dragon arrayDragon[]){
    //Debe ordenar en base los ps de cada dragon

    //Algoritmo de ordenamiento ascendente

    //iteramos sobre el arreglo
    for(int i=0 ; i<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
        int min = i;
        //Se busca el menor numero
        for(int j=0 ; j<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
            if(arrayDragon[j].getPS() < arrayDragon[min].getPS()){
                min = j;  //encontramos el menor numero
            }
        }

        if(i != min){
            //cambiamos los valores
            Dragon aux = arrayDragon[i];
            arrayDragon[i] = arrayDragon[min];
            arrayDragon[min] = aux;

        }
    }
    //aca termina el algoritmo
}

public static int danoRecibido(Dragon arrayDragon[]){
    int suma = 0;
    int danoTotal = 0;

    for(int i=0 ; i < arrayDragon.length ; i++){
        suma += arrayDragon[i].getDPS();  //cont de daño de todos los dragones desde el 0 al n-1

    }
    for(int i=0 ; i<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
        if(i==0){
            danoTotal = suma*arrayDragon[i].getPS(); //cuenta el daño total recibido por todos los dragones vivos
        }

        else{
            suma = suma - arrayDragon[i-1].getDPS();
            danoTotal = suma*arrayDragon[i].getPS();
        }                                                                    //Le resta el daño del dragon derrotado y cuenta el daño
        //que le inflingen los dragones vivos
    }

    return danoTotal;
}
```

}

**El problema que tengo es que no se porque no me imprime después de la funcion ordenaDragones() la funcion danoRecibido()**

Comment: ¿Qué se imprime si pones la instrucción `System.out.println(arrayDragon.length);`, antes y después de llamar a `ordenaDragones()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dps = 0;
        int ps = 0;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese un entero de dragones");

        int n = reader.nextInt();

        Dragon arrayDragon[] = new Dragon[n];//declara el arreglo tipo dragon

        for(int i=0 ; i<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
            arrayDragon[i] = new Dragon(dps, ps); //instansiamos(crear) el objeto

            System.out.println("Ingrese el dps del dragon"+ (i+1));
            dps = reader.nextInt();

            arrayDragon[i].setDPS(dps);

            System.out.println("Ingrese los ps del dragon"+ (i+1));
            ps = reader.nextInt();

            arrayDragon[i].setPS(ps);
        }
        ordenaDragones(arrayDragon);

        for(int i=0 ; i<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
            System.out.println("El dragon "+ (i+1) +" tiene un dps de");
            System.out.println(arrayDragon[i].getDPS() +" dps");
            System.out.println("El dragon "+ (i+1) +" tiene ");
            System.out.println(arrayDragon[i].getPS() +" ps");

        }

        System.out.println("El daño recibido del mago es");
        System.out.println(danoRecibido(arrayDragon));

    }

    public static void ordenaDragones(Dragon arrayDragon[]){
        //Debe ordenar en base los ps de cada dragon

        //Algoritmo de ordenamiento ascendente

        //iteramos sobre el arreglo
        for(int i=0 ; i<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
            int min = i;
            //Se busca el menor numero
            for(int j=0 ; j<arrayDragon.length ; j++){//Aquí ponía i++, con lo cual entraba en un bucle infinito donde j siempre era menor que arrayDragon.length
                if(arrayDragon[j].getPS() < arrayDragon[min].getPS()){
                    min = j;  //encontramos el menor numero
                }
            }

            if(i != min){
                //cambiamos los valores
                Dragon aux = arrayDragon[i];
                arrayDragon[i] = arrayDragon[min];
                arrayDragon[min] = aux;
            }
        }
        //aca termina el algoritmo
    }

    public static int danoRecibido(Dragon arrayDragon[]){
        int suma = 0;
        int danoTotal = 0;

        for(int i=0 ; i < arrayDragon.length ; i++){
            suma += arrayDragon[i].getDPS();  //cont de daño de todos los dragones desde el 0 al n-1

        }
        for(int i=0 ; i<arrayDragon.length ; i++){
            if(i==0){
                danoTotal = suma*arrayDragon[i].getPS(); //cuenta el daño total recibido por todos los dragones vivos
            }

            else{
                suma = suma - arrayDragon[i-1].getDPS();
                danoTotal = suma*arrayDragon[i].getPS();
            }                                                                    //Le resta el daño del dragon derrotado y cuenta el daño
            //que le inflingen los dragones vivos
        }

        return danoTotal;
    }
}
```

El error estaba en la declaración del bucle interno (j++) del método para ordenar los dragones. También tenías varios errores en la impresión de los datos, te los he corregido.
Además, en java se declaran los array como Dragon[] arrayDragon, la manera en que lo haces tú es costumbre en C

Comment: Entiendo el error(bastante torpe jeje), gracias con respecto a las declaraciones de los arreglos, estoy recién pasándome de c a java